# Select dates with a time of less than 14:00:00 and higher than 06:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all records from date `2018-10-01` to date `2018-10-09`. 
I would shorten the number of results over time over 06:00:00 and less then 14:00:00.

I did the following:

```
$radno_vr = ' 14:00:00';
    $pocetak_smjene = ' 06:00:00';
    $od_datuma_tabl = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $od_datuma)->format('Y-m-d' . $pocetak_smjene); 
    $do_datuma_tabl = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $do_datuma)->format('Y-m-d' . $radno_vr); 

      $trazi_podatke = "SELECT * FROM podaci_kotl WHERE sifra_objekta = '$sifra_objekta_trazi' AND datum > '$od_datuma_tabl' AND datum < '$do_datuma_tabl' ... ";
```

But It works fine, the date over takes all the results longer than 06:00:00 to 14:00:00 but from the last selected date.
I'm trying to make a selection from **every day** but only if there is a record between 06:00:00 and 14:00:00..
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use BETWEEN Value1 AND Value2 statement.

Comment: That wouldn't help, would it? He wants values for every day

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow yeah, but for every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter on time.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

`[...] AND TIME(datum) > TIME('$od_datuma_tabl') AND TIME(datum) < TIME('$do_datuma_tabl')`